# Restricciones del operador ternario ?:

Tags: c++, operador-ternario

Tengo este pedazo de código:

```
(comprar >= 1 && comprar <= 40) ? ActualizarAsientos(Asientos, comprar) : cout << "Asiento fuera de rango";
```

Donde la primera condición es un `void` y la segunda una salida de texto, sin embargo el compilador (Visual Studio 2017) no me lo reconoce. Pienso que me pide que ambas condiciones sean del mismo tipo, o ambos un `cout` o ambos un `void`, ¿alguien sabe si existe esa restricción o si estoy cometiendo algún otro error?

Comment: Hola ALEJANDRO SAENZ, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 6):

El operador ternario no es "una forma compacta de if/else", sino una *expresión* que tiene que producir un *resultado* de un tipo concreto, ya que su uso habitual es en asignaciones.

El resultado del operador ternario típicamente se asigna a una variable, por lo que el compilador debe poder comprobar si el tipo del resultado coincide con el tipo de la variable. No puede hacer esta comprobación si cada "rama" del operador ternario produce como resultado un tipo diferente.

En tu caso, podrías tener una función, por ejemplo `ImprimirError()` que retorne `void` para usarla en la segunda parte del operador ternario.

Pero ya que en tu caso no estás asignando el resultado a ningún lugar ¿por qué usar el operador ternario? Simplemente cámbialo por un if/else. Además ganará en legibilidad.

Answer (score 5):

> El compilador (Visual Studio 2017) no me lo reconoce

Y hace bien en no reconocerlo, pues está siguiendo las instrucciones del [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) en la sección §8.16 (traducción mía):

> #### 8.16 Operador Condicional
>
> 1. […]
> 2. Si el primer o el segundo operando tiene tipo `void`, una de las siguientes condiciones debe cumplirse:
>
>    1. El segundo o tercer operando (pero no ambos) es una *expresión-throw* (posiblemente entre paréntesis); el resultado es del tipo y categoría del otro. La *expresión-condicional* es un campo de bits si ese operando es un campo de bits.
>    2. Tanto el segundo como el tercer operando es de tipo `void`, el resultado es de tipo `void` y es un valor puro del lado derecho […].

Dado que no se cumple ninguna de las condiciones para aceptar que alguno de los operandos sea de tipo `void`, el programa falla. Pero es fácil de solucionar:

```
(comprar >= 1 && comprar <= 40) ?
    ActualizarAsientos(Asientos, comprar) :
    (void)(cout << "Asiento fuera de rango");
//  ~~~~~~ <-- conversión a void
```

Si ambas expresiones son de tipo `void` se cumple §8.16.2.2 y compila correctamente. Pero no es una buena idea, sigue el consejo de [abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/155932/2742) y cambia el código por un `if`-`else`:

```
if (comprar >= 1 && comprar <= 40)
    ActualizarAsientos(Asientos, comprar);
else
    cout << "Asiento fuera de rango";
```

O haz que cumpla §8.16.2.1 y captura la excepción en algún sitio:

```
(comprar >= 1 && comprar <= 40) ?
    ActualizarAsientos(Asientos, comprar) :
    (throw std::logic_error{"Asiento fuera de rango"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno una solucion basica es meter el mensaje dentro de un metodo void, dado que estos condicionales se utilizan para returnar un valor;

```
variable=condicion?valorSiEsTrue:valorSiEsFalse;
```

Comment: El operador ternario no necesariamente se usa para *returnar* un valor, si el segundo y tercer operando es `void` de hecho no devuelve nada y no se puede hacer lo que dices: `esto_es_error = condicion ? devuelve_void() : devuelve_void();`